# How to set a relation between two entities Code First, EntityFramework

Tags: ef-code-first, addition, relation

I have a relation between two objects/rows in MSSQL using EF code first.
However, if I do:

```
obj1.Add(obj2)
```

That would make EF create a new row in the database of obj2, no matter if obj2 already exists in the table or not.

What if I dont want it to always create a new copy of obj2 in the database, but to actually use an existing one if one exists?

I know that I could simply check if obj2 already exists in the db, but the problem is that Im not sure of how to assocaite obj2 to obj1 using code first in a one to many relation-ship. (obj1 1<--->* obj2)

Br,
Inx

Comment: Or would this be the behavior of a faulty configured relation-ship? Since I have not set any foreign-keys or configured any relations with the fluent-api..

Comment: If obj2 already exists you could do an Attach or you could set its state to EntityState.Unchanged. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: can you include your class definitions?